# ZF does not catch exception

Tags: zend-framework, exception

I'm trying to get my log writer working, however, I don't get that far.

When I throw an exception:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        throw new Exception('something bad happened!');
    }
}
```

it is not being caught by my errorcontroller.

checked my version is 1.11.4 with env development. I'm not sure what is wrong here, any help appreciated. I find it very weird.

```
( ! ) Exception: something bad happened! in C:\sites\mysite\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 7
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  350304  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0705  5273208 Zend_Application->run( )    ..\index.php:31
3   0.0705  5273208 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run( )    ..\Application.php:366
4   0.0705  5273384 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:97
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think you have `throwExceptions` set to `1` for your dev enviroment in your application.ini ;)

Comment: Did you mean `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions`?

Comment: No, he means `resources.frontController.throwExceptions`

Comment: When I got home to check your answer, it was working :( Gave you the mark anyway since when I added it to my application.ini (it was not there though) the exception was again not caught. making it 0 solved my issue. Thanks, I don't know why it didn't happen last night, but at least now you gave me the line to 'ensure' it does not happen :)